# how to store a 2D game world in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am making a 2D game in javascript/ajax, that will be using data stored in mysql database. Every user have got his own "area" made of small squares that can have some values. But I have no idea, how to store values of each square in mysql, when each user can have area with different width or height. Do you have some idea?

Comment: Are the squares equal size? Can they overlap?

Comment: The squares have the same size and are set in one big rectangle, like in other 2D games :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about storing the rectangle's four corners (x0, y0, x1, y1)? If you have an index on them, querying should be fairly efficient too, but your mileage may vary...

Comment: Seems more viable than a many-to-many relation table (which @dario suggested).

Comment: @strager: I fail to see a many to many in @dario's solution. (maybe re deleted and resubmitted?) 
His idea is an extension of AKX's by adding a table for user data (thus N users to 1 square)

Comment: @lexu, @AKX's answer requires only a few fields in the user's table, no matter the size of the area.  @dario's answer requires a `USERSQUARES` table with e.g. 25 entries for a 5x5 square.

Comment: @strager: got it, thanks for the explanation, I completely failed to understand AKX's design .. I assumed storing all squares, not what he suggested, mea culpa!

Answer (score 2):

You should store data like this

```
SQUARES(squareId, XYdataOfSqare)
USERSQUARES(userId, squareId)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just save the coordinates, one entry for each square per user.

Table structure:

```
id 
square_x 
square_y
user_id
```

id is auto incrementing, square_x and square_y is for the square's position.

You can then insert every user's squares with single records.